# errors in install ubuntu-app-launch

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates, dpkg

i try to upgrade my ubuntu to 17.04
after reboot if i run `apt dist-upgrade` tell me :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libubuntu-app-launch4 : Depends: ubuntu-app-launch (= 0.11+17.04.20170321-0ubuntu1) but 0.9+16.10.20160928-0ubuntu1 is installed
 ubuntu-app-launch-tools : Depends: ubuntu-app-launch (= 0.11+17.04.20170321-0ubuntu1) but 0.9+16.10.20160928-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

if i run `apt -f install` or `apt-get -f install` tell me :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ubuntu-app-launch
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ubuntu-app-launch
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1103 not upgraded.
187 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/14.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 101 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 441897 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ubuntu-app-launch_0.11+17.04.20170321-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 55, in <module>
    from click import commands
ImportError: cannot import name 'commands'
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-app-launch_0.11+17.04.20170321-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 there is no script in the new version of the package - giving up
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ubuntu-app-launch_0.11+17.04.20170321-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

according to this link [Dpkg errors after update to 16.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837775/dpkg-errors-after-update-to-16-10) i try `apt autoremove -f click click-apparmor ubuntu-app-launch` and tell me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libubuntu-app-launch4 : Depends: ubuntu-app-launch (= 0.11+17.04.20170321-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 ubuntu-app-launch-tools : Depends: ubuntu-app-launch (= 0.11+17.04.20170321-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 unity8-desktop-session : Depends: ubuntu-app-launch but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

What can I do?!

Comment: Do you have a 64 or 32 bit system?

Comment: i have 64 bit system